# Human friendly date logic library in java

Tags: java, datetime, expressionengine

So a question, is there a library out there that will allow me to do some datetime logic in human friendly format? For example, if I want to check if given date is within next month then I'll query submit if statement ${date} <= now + 1 month and it'll return true/false. The basic idea is do design jsp tag or function for el to do date operations and display sections of data to the client:

```
<bla:cond test="${datetime} <= now + 1 month">within next month</bla:cond>
<bla:cond test="${datetime} > now + 2 seconds && ${datetime} < now + 3 seconds">in 2 seconds</bla:cond>
```

Something like that. The idea is to have some datetime logic with easy to change/read arithmetic lexicon.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

joda-time for date arithmetic and [pretty-time](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) for human friendly display

Comment: Didn't know pretty-time. Nice! (+1)

Comment: Thanks. We're already using both. Just thought to simplify the logic.

Comment: This site seems to be dead. returns a 404

Comment: @Andrew fixed it now

Answer (score 3):

[JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is usually what comes to mind. It also has a [JSP tag library](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/contrib/jsptags/).

But I'd do the processing in a Controller and output only data in the JSP.